# android xml design construction

Tags: android, xml

I am designing an app in xml android. I have been using lots of drawable resources. The thing is, when i test the design in an emulator of size 800x800 it runs fine. but as i decrease the size of the emulator to 500x500 the design starts breaking out. Its not completely in the same position. I have used a lot of layout_margin attributes. please tell if there is any other way by which my design runs fine irrespective of size of the emulator!?

a snip of my code is:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:id="@+id/containers"
           android:src="@drawable/containers" 
           android:paddingTop="42px" 
           android:paddingLeft="3px">
</ImageView>
<TextView android:textColor="#000000"
          android:paddingLeft="20px" 
          android:paddingTop="58px" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/current_loc"
          android:text="@string/current_loc" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<TextView android:textColor="#000000"
          android:paddingLeft="20px"
          android:paddingTop="109px" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:id="@+id/current_loc" 
          android:text="@string/at" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<Button android:text="@string/time" 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:id="@+id/pickTime" 
        android:layout_height="50px" 
        android:layout_width="120px" 
        android:layout_marginTop="100px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40px">
</Button>
<Button android:text="@string/date"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/pickDate"
        android:layout_height="50px" 
        android:layout_marginTop="100px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160px"
        android:layout_width="100px">
</Button>
<TextView android:textColor="#000000" 
          android:layout_marginLeft="260px"
          android:id="@+id/to" 
          android:layout_marginTop="110px" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:text="@string/to" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<EditText android:textColor="#000000" 
          android:id="@+id/editText2" 
          android:layout_marginTop="97px" 
          android:layout_marginLeft="280px"
          android:layout_height="60px" 
          android:layout_width="190px"
          android:hint="@string/dest" 
          android:textSize="20px" 
          android:singleLine="True">
</EditText>
<TextView android:textColor="#000000" 
          android:paddingLeft="20px" 
          android:id="@+id/thereare"  
          android:paddingTop="180px" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:text="@string/ihave" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<EditText android:textColor="#000000" 
          android:id="@+id/num1" 
          android:layout_marginTop="169px"
          android:layout_height="55px"
          android:layout_width="50px"
          android:layout_marginLeft="85px" 
          android:hint="2"></EditText>
<TextView android:textColor="#000000" 
          android:paddingLeft="140px" 
          android:id="@+id/female"
          android:paddingTop="180px"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/female" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<TextView android:textColor="#000000"
          android:paddingLeft="210px"
          android:id="@+id/and" 
          android:paddingTop="180px" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:text="@string/and" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to get rid of specifying sizes in pixels. Instead you can use dip and layout_weights

Answer (score 3):

To make xml design works properly on any screen device, wrap your widget around `RelativeLayout` and change you measurement unit from `px` to `dp`. With `dp` unit you will get relative measurement that change depends on the screen resolution.

For more info, refer to this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: What exactly do u needin xml  i can made it for u

Answer (score 1):

You can specify different layout .xml files for different screen resolutions, to avoid your problem. Read carefully the guidelines that Android Developers site gives [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

try using this code now may be it would be helpful for u

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#8B8989" android:orientation="vertical">
```

write down your XML in betweenthis code

```
</LinearLayout>
```